# Why is change of basis using a double augmented matrix always in columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For example, when finding change of bases $P_{a \leftarrow b}$ such that it goes from polynomial of degree one to polynomial of degree one, $P_1 \rightarrow P_1$, then I put the polynomial in column vector form for the augmented matrix instead of row vectors. For $a=[2+x,3+4x]$ & $b=[9+6x, 8+7x]$, why is this augmented matrix **correct**:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 3 &|& 9 & 8 \\
1 & 4 &|& 6 & 7 
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$

while this, my original method, is **incorrect**:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 1 &|& 9 & 6 \\
3 & 4 &|& 8 & 7 
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$

I know I reduce the left side to the identity and the right side then becomes my transition matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $e_i$ be the elements of one basis of $V$ and let $f_i$ be the elements of another basis. The change of basis matrix from $e_i$ to $f_i$ has as its entries the scalars $a_{ij}$ such that $f_i = \sum_j a_{ij}e_j$. If you associate $e_i$ with the standard basis on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the columns of the matrix will be the coordinate representation of the new basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For example, with the polynomials you mention we have 
\begin{aligned}
e_1 &= 2+x\\
e_2 &= 3+4x\\
\end{aligned}
and
\begin{aligned}
f_1 &= 9+6x\\
f_2 &= 8+7x.\\
\end{aligned}
since
\begin{aligned}
f_1 &= 3.6 e_1 + 0.6 e_2\\
f_2 &= 2.2 e_1 + 1.2 e_2,
\end{aligned}
(please check my work to make sure there are no fat-finger-induced Matlab typing errors...)
it follows that the change of basis matrix is 
\begin{aligned}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
3.6 & 0.6\\
2.2 & 1.2\\
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{aligned}

Now: why the first augmented matrix and not the second?

Note that to find the matrix above you need to solve the system
\begin{aligned}
a_{11}(2+x) + a_{12}(3+4x) &= 9 + 6x\\
a_{21}(2+x) + a_{22}(3+4x) &= 8 + 7x.\\
\end{aligned}
Since $1$ and $x$ are a basis of $P_1(\mathbb{R})$, they are linearly independent, so we can rewrite this as 
\begin{aligned}
2a_{11} + 3a_{12} &= 9\\
a_{11} + 4a_{12} &= 6\\
2a_{21} + 3a_{22} &= 8\\
a_{21} + 4a_{22} &= 7,\\
\end{aligned}
which is equivalent to the simultaneous equations
\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3\\
1 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}\\
a_{12}\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
9\\
6\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
and
\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3\\
1 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{21}\\
a_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
8\\
7\\
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{aligned}
These two lead to the first augmented matrix rather than the second.